# Getting XMLHttpRequest cannot load on second api call Instagram

Tags: javascript, json, api, instagram

I'm making a call to the instagram api to get all pictures with a certain tag, the first time it works fine it shows me on console the json, but when I try to call again with the next_url to get all pictures I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?callback=jQuery18300975…092&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&max_tag_id=1395937138154027. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var Instagram = {};

// Small object for holding important configuration data.
Instagram.Config = {
   clientID: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
   apiHost: 'https://api.instagram.com'
 };

(function(){
var url;
function search(tag){
   generateResource(tag);
  $.getJSON(url, toScreen);
}

function generateResource(tag){
url = Instagram.Config.apiHost + "/v1/tags/" + tag + "/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=" +     Instagram.Config.clientID;
return url;
}

function toScreen(data){
  var next_url=data.pagination.next_url;
  console.log(next_url)
  if(next_url!=undefined)
  {
     url=next_url;
     pagination(url);
     console.log(data);
  }
}
function pagination(url)
{
   $.getJSON(url, toScreen);
}

 Instagram.App = {
   search: search
 };


}());

$(function(){
  Instagram.App.search('cats');  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add another `&callback=?` for `next_url`

Modify like this and try it works:

```
  if(next_url!=undefined)
  {
     url=next_url + "&callback=?";
     pagination(url);
     console.log(data);
  }
```